# angular7 building an navroute component but don't know what to do now

Tags: html, angular

**there is no issue with this code**

to be more specific

**can I create value's within my angular HTML or not?**

I couldn't find anything about it so I think not and what do I do now if I want to create an automated menu.
i am using angular materials in this

I need to create a nav bar but I created it in angular HTML with some stuff in TS to create the data it needs to be automatic

so I need to loop this bottom part of my code with any value but I don't know how to start

```html
        <!-- need to loop this block of code whenever there is any new item with children -->
                    <div *ngFor="let childss of childs.children">
                      <div *ngIf="childss.children != null">
                        
                      </div>
                      <a routerLink="/{{navRoute.path}}/{{childs.path}}/{{childss.path}}"><button mat-menu-item>{{childss.path}}</button></a>
                    </div>
        
                  </mat-menu>
              </div>
              <ng-template #elsesBlock>
                <a routerLink="/{{navRoute.path}}/{{childs.path}}"><button mat-menu-item>{{childs.path}}</button></a>
              </ng-template>
              <!-- till here but have no idee how to do this effectively -->
```

childs is an item of an array

but it needs custom input data for the loop to function correctly but I have no idea how to do it if

```html
  
  <div class="nav_items" *ngFor="let navRoute of navRoutes">
      <div *ngIf="navRoute.children != null; else elseBlock">
        
        <div *ngIf="navRoute.children != null">
          <a routerLink="/{{navRoute.path}}">
            <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">{{navRoute.path}}</button>
          </a>

          <mat-menu #menu="matMenu"> 

            <div *ngFor="let childs of navRoute.children">
              
              <div *ngIf="childs.children != null; else elsesBlock">
                  <a routerLink="/{{navRoute.path}}/{{childs.path}}">
                    <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="child">{{childs.path}}</button>
                  </a>
        
                  <mat-menu #child="matMenu"> 
        <!-- need to loop this blok of code when ever there is anny new item with children -->
                    <div *ngFor="let childss of childs.children">
                      <div *ngIf="childss.children != null">
                        
                      </div>
                      <a routerLink="/{{navRoute.path}}/{{childs.path}}/{{childss.path}}"><button mat-menu-item>{{childss.path}}</button></a>
                    </div>
        
                  </mat-menu>
              </div>
              <ng-template #elsesBlock>
                <a routerLink="/{{navRoute.path}}/{{childs.path}}"><button mat-menu-item>{{childs.path}}</button></a>
              </ng-template>
              <!-- till here but have no idee how to do this effectively -->
            </div>

          </mat-menu>        
        </div>
        
      </div>
        
      <ng-template #elseBlock>
        
        <a routerLink="/{{navRoute.path}}">
          <button mat-button>{{navRoute.path}}</button>
        </a>

      </ng-template>

 </div>
```

this is my entire HTML

nav route is an array from my routes

I tried HTML link but that doesn't work with angular items

Comment: So what isn't working, exactly?

Comment: please explain us what is your issue?

Comment: it works but I need to loop the first block of code but don't know how to start because the values are hard coded

Comment: Loop it how? Based on what? There is also already a loop present, you mean that? The html fragment is also not complete, there are 2 elements missing at the top, you can't take a partial html fragment and repeat it if the fragment is incomplete.

Comment: i want to make it that it doesn't matter how many childs of childs are from my routing that it would still create an menu

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax for your routerLink:

```
[routerLink]="['/' + navRoute.path + '/' + childs.path]"
```